# Error compiling mysqlnd_qc with apc

Tags: php, memcached, apc, amazon-rds, mysqlnd

Running the command `pecl install mysqlnd_qc` to install the caching with `APC` enabled I receive the following error:

```
configure: error: APC is onlysupported if both APC and MySQL Query Cache are compiled statically
ERROR: `/var/tmp/mysqlnd_qc/configure --enable-mysqlnd-qc-apc=yes --enable-qc-memcache=no --enable-qc-sqlite=no' failed
```

Without the APC enabled it compiles fine...

PHP version: 5.3.17

Running on Amazon RDS.

**What does it mean to compile APC and MySQL Query Cache statically?**

How is it done?

---

**Update 1:**

As I haven't managed to compile mysqlnd_qc with APC, I tried compiling it with `memcached`.
Here was an interesting issue. The `./configure` command didn't recognize the the option the `pecl` gave for `memcache`. I found out that the option was entered incorrectly...

So I killed the `pecl` installation when it was asking for the options and ran the following commands myself:

```
sudo ./configure --enable-mysqlnd-qc-memcache --with-libmemcached-dir=/usr/
sudo make
sudo make install
```

So with `memcached` it now works.

If running on `Fedora` (I guess also `RedHat` and `CentOS`) there is available a `rpm`:

```
sudo yum install php-pecl-mysqlnd-qc
```

---

**Update 2:**

I managed to compile with APC, see the detailed answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well found the solution:

Here is what I did:

Get php 5.3.17:

```
wget https://github.com/php/php-src/archive/PHP-5.3.17.zip
unzip PHP-5.3.17.zip
```

Get mysqlnd_qc:

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/mysqlnd_qc-1.1.1.tgz
tar -zxvf http://pecl.php.net/get/mysqlnd_qc-1.1.1.tgz
mkdir -p php-src-PHP-5.3.17/ext/mysqlnd_qc
cp -R mysqlnd_qc-1.1.1/* php-src-PHP-5.3.17/ext/mysqlnd_qc
```

Get APC:

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/APC-3.1.13.tgz
tar -xzvf APC-3.1.13.tgz
mkdir -p php-src-PHP-5.3.17/ext/apc
cp -R APC-3.1.13/* php-src-PHP-5.3.17/ext/apc/
```

Compile: (maybe don't need all on other systems)

```
sudo yum install bison
sudo yum install libxml2 libxml2-devel
sudo yum install autoconf213
sudo yum install httpd-devel
sudo yum install bzip2 lbzip2 bzip2-libs bzip2-devel

export PHP_AUTOCONF=/usr/bin/autoconf-2.13

./buildconf --force
make clean && make
```

(for me the linkage failed and had to add '-lpthread' to linkage)

```
make test
sudo make install
```

I used also the following 2 commands but I don't remember for what and when...

```
phpize
aclocal
```

Run the same `./configure` as in phpinfo and add these options:

```
--with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --enable-mysqlnd-qc --enable-mysqlnd-qc-apc --enable-mysqlnd --enable-apc --enable-static=apc
```

- **All the `--with` must be replaced.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to compile from source giving the right .configure options. 
pecl install just gives you a .so, which is a dynamic module extension, you can add via php.ini

So if you really need mysqlnd_qc with apc (do you?), you have to get the php src, and compile it
with the needed modules.

If you don´t need it, just say no or hit return when pecl install mysqlnd_qc ask you about it.

Comment: pecl install, at least on my linux version does compile the code (using make and gcc) and creates the so file on the fly. I need the APC otherwise the query caching will affect only the running process and that's almost useless....